# Using ArcGIS to measure distance between two points along a line

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

[image]

I am trying to measure the distance between two bus stops along the bus stop route.    I've been trying to use Locate Features Along Routes to measure this distance, but I don't know if the resulting table is accurate - or I'm not sure how to interpret it.[image]

I understand that Distance is the distance from each point to the line, but does Meas show the distance along the line?  I've measured it manually and is about 5000 feet.

Edit: I realized that the "Meas" column dictates the distance from the beginning of the line to the first and second points.  I also dissolved the line so it was not segmented.

Comment: Do you have M-values in your Routes layer? Also, which coordinate system and units are you using?

Comment: If a single measurement is required, then I will suggest deploying [the Measure tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/measuring-distances-and-areas.htm) on the Tools toolbar.

Comment: Yes, the routes layer has M-Values.  I just converted both to NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Feet, but I still don't think the measure column is correct.  For FID 1 it's 916.576025 and for FID it's 1456.975971

Answer (score 1):

This [Esri Blog](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/mapping/calculate-chainage-or-distance-of-points-along-a-polyline/) has a good [linear referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm) solution:

1. Convert your bus route polylines to routes using [Create Routes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/create-routes.htm)
2. Then use [Locate Features Along Routes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/linear-referencing/locate-features-along-routes.htm)